Number of all possible arrangements such that no two objects of same kind are together
There are $k_1+k_2+k_3+...+k_n$ objects of which $k_1$ are of first kind, $k_2$ are of second kind, $k_3$ are of third kind, ..., $k_n$ are of $n^{th}$ kind. Calculate the number of all possible arrangements of all these objects in a row such that no two objects of the same kind are adjacent.
I am able to solve for the cases when $k_i$ and $n$ are small (For example, $n=5, k_1=3, k_2 = 2, k_3 =1, k_4 = 1, k_5 = 1$). Is there any general formula for the total number of such arrangements?

Does $k_r,0<r<n$ represent a single object?

@Gwen $k_r$ represents the number of objects of $r^{th}$ kind. No, it does not represent a single object.
